# Error uploading JSON data and Image in single API call: Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, file-upload, postman, multipartform-data

I am working on a Spring Boot Project where I want to send **JSON data and Multipart File** (Image) in a single API call. For this, I referred- [https://blogs.perficient.com/2020/07/27/requestbody-and-multipart-on-spring-boot/#:~:text=Usually%20we%20add%20%40RequestBody%20and,So%2C%20annotation%20should%20be%20altered](https://blogs.perficient.com/2020/07/27/requestbody-and-multipart-on-spring-boot/#:%7E:text=Usually%20we%20add%20%40RequestBody%20and,So%2C%20annotation%20should%20be%20altered).
My **Controller** is-

```
@PostMapping(value = "/create",consumes = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE})
        public ResponseEntity<SuccessResponse<PostDto>> createPost(
                @RequestPart("post") String post,
                        @RequestPart("image") MultipartFile file,
                        @RequestParam(name = "userid") Integer uid,
                        @RequestParam(name = "categoryid") Integer categoryId) {

                log.info("Filename :" + file.getOriginalFilename());
                log.info("Size:" + file.getSize());
                log.info("Contenttype:" + file.getContentType());

                //convert the post string to POJO
                 PostDto postDto=postService.getJson(post);
                //Now create the post
                 PostDto newPost = this.postService.createPost(postDto, uid, categoryId, file);
                SuccessResponse<PostDto> successResponse = new SuccessResponse<>(AppConstants.SUCCESS_CODE,
                                AppConstants.SUCCESS_MESSAGE, newPost);
                return new ResponseEntity<>(successResponse, HttpStatus.OK);
        }
```

I am using **Postman** for testing-
[image: Request Example]

When I make the request, I get the following error (Note- I  have set the error response in Spring Security as seen in the image.)

```
[nio-8085-exec-3] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MissingServletRequestPartException: Required part 'image' is not present.]
```

I tried another approach but it gives another error-

```
 @PostMapping("/uploadimage/{postid}/{isUpdatingPost}")
        public ResponseEntity<SuccessResponse<String>> uploadImage(@RequestParam(name="file") MultipartFile file, @PathVariable("postid") int postid, @PathVariable("isUpdatingPost")boolean isUpdatingPost){
                String result=this.postService.uploadImage(file, postid, isUpdatingPost);
                SuccessResponse<String> response=new SuccessResponse<>(AppConstants.SUCCESS_CODE,AppConstants.SUCCESS_MESSAGE,result);
                return new ResponseEntity<>(response,HttpStatus.OK);
        }
```

```
[Request processing failed: org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: Current request is not a multipart request] with root cause

org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: Current request is not a multipart request
```

I am not able to understand the problem in these approaches. I also set the content type to **multipart/form-data in Postman** and the **consume** parameter in **@PostMapping**, but still getting these errors.
Please help in finding the problem!

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

For attaching single file with `@RequestParam`:

```
@PostMapping(consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<?> uploadImage(@RequestParam MultipartFile file) throws IOException {
    // ...
}
```

For attaching file in DTO with `@ModelAttribute`:

```
public record FileDTO(
        Integer id,
        MultipartFile file) {
}

@PostMapping(value = "/2", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE, produces = MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<?> uploadImage2(@ModelAttribute FileDTO dto) throws IOException {
    // ...
}
```

BTW, you probably want use OpenAPI(Swagger UI) for manually testing your app, it's easier than using postman.

Reference article: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-file-upload